# Oracle Managed Data Access and C# web application

Tags: c#, oracle, web

I am pulling my hair out. 
I have an Oracle package that uses a merge statement (also tried a normal update statement). My c# web prog sends parameters to the procedure. I have debugged and made sure the connection is correct, the parameters are passing, the datatypes match.

I have granted the user in the webconfig to have exec access on the package.

I have even granted the user to have update on the table.

If I use inline SQL in the C# program, the update gets executed.

Any thoughts? For what it is worth...I hate Oracle.

```
    PROCEDURE NAME_INSUPD_SITECOMMENT(SITEID IN INT, SITECOMMENTS IN VARCHAR2,
                                       LOCKID IN INT, EMPID IN INT)
    IS
    BEGIN
        MERGE INTO <TABLE>
        USING DUAL ON (SITE_ID = SITEID)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN        
            UPDATE
            SET
                SITE_COMMENTS = SITECOMMENTS,
                SITE_MODIFY_USER = EMPID,
                SITE_MODIFY_DATE = SYSDATE,
                LOCK_ID = LOCKID + 1
            WHERE
                SITE_ID = SITEID AND
                LOCK_ID = LOCKID
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT(SITE_COMMENTS,SITE_MODIFY_USER,SITE_MODIFY_DATE,LOCK_ID)
            VALUES(SITECOMMENTS,EMPID,SYSDATE,LOCKID);
    END NAME_INSUPD_SITECOMMENT;

C#
 internal static Site SaveSiteComment(Site s, int empId)
        {
            OracleConnection conn = ConnUtilities.GetOracleConnection("MyConnectionString");
            OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand();

            comm.Connection = conn;
            //comm.CommandText = "PACKAGENAME.INSUPD_SITECOMMENT";
            //comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.CommandText = "UPDATE <TABLE> SET SITE_COMMENTS = '" + s.SiteComments.Trim() +"', SITE_MODIFY_USER = " + empId + ",SITE_MODIFY_DATE = SYSDATE, LOCK_ID = " + s.LockId + " WHERE SITE_ID = " + s.Identifier + " AND LOCK_ID = " + s.LockId;
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SITEID", OracleDbType.Int32, s.Identifier, ParameterDirection.Input));
            comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SITECOMMENTS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, s.SiteComments.Trim(), ParameterDirection.Input));
            comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("LOCKID", OracleDbType.Int32, s.LockId, ParameterDirection.Input));
            comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EMPID", OracleDbType.Int32, empId, ParameterDirection.Input));

            bool isNew = s.Identifier <= 0;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                s.SetClean();

                return s;
            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
                comm.Dispose();

                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                comm.Dispose();
                conn.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you're doing?  And what error you're getting?

Comment: Show us your code and the error message.

Comment: Brian/Wernfried...there isn't any error. But I will do my best to post.

Comment: Here is the C# code...note <TABLE> is a placeholder, PACKAGENAME is also a placeholder as I am obviously not putting actual names in.

Comment: Ok last couple of bits of info. This is but one procedure in the package. So far, all have been SELECT statements and all work. I created a public synonym for the package. I granted EXECUTE on the synonym (which contains the procedures and SELECTS are working). I also granted UPDATE to the specific table to the user in the WEBCONFIG. When I look at DBA_OBJECTS, the owner is PUBLIC. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Lastly, if I do NOT use a merge and just a plain old UPDATE statement where the MERGE is above, it does NOT work either.

Comment: Try changing the parameter calls to look like this:
comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SITEID", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value = s.Identifier;

Comment: Of course you don't get an error, your exception handler suppress any error message. Return the error message in order to see it.

Comment: Your command string is wrong. Check Oracle documentation for prepared statements.

Comment: @Wernfried - command string is fine. If it wasn't I wouldn't be able to run the application. ConnUtilities is a dll I developed that I use extensively in all my applications, including this one.

Comment: @BrianM - I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. I didn't try changing for it all params. I may try that. I copied the MERGE statement from a procedure in another application I wrote that works, so I am confident that it isn't the MERGE statement. By using MERGE, INSERT and UPDATE statements can be combined.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding `OracleParameter`s to the command but you don't actually have those parameters specified in the CommandText. Try this:

```
comm.CommandText = "UPDATE <TABLE> SET SITE_COMMENTS = :SITECOMMENTS, SITE_MODIFY_USER = :EMPID, SITE_MODIFY_DATE = SYSDATE WHERE SITE_ID = :SITEID";
```

(Note: I've removed the LockId stuff because you were updating it to the value it was already set to)

Comment: it is not incorrect. The hardcoded update statement above, works. I want to call the stored procedure rather than the hardcoded update statement.

Comment: As far as the LockId, yes, here I was setting it to the same value. That was a copy and paste error...the SET should be Lock_ID = LockID + 1

Answer (score 0):

If I neglected to convey how very much I DESPISE Oracle with every fiber of my being, let me state it emphatically: I HATE IT.

Anyways, 2 FREAKING days on this...at least 5 dozen articles, examples, and even breaking out and hard coding the values...I added a FREAKING P_ to all the params and it worked. THAT. IS. ALL. I. DID.

I. HATE. ORACLE.